# Generate table from JSON file and use colorbox for each link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, lightbox, colorbox

When I try to read the table data from a JSON file, I find that the color box is not working, and don't know why, any idea?
This is my code:

```
 $.getJSON("resource/candidateJob.json",function(data){
    $('#candidateTable').empty();
    var htmlInfo = '';
    htmlInfo +=
        '<tr><th>Jobs</th>'+
            '<th>Company Name</th>'+
            '<th>Industry</th>'+
            '<th>Location</th>'+
            '<th>Time</th>'+
            '<th>Detail</th></tr>';
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
        //alert(i);
        if(i>=(pageIndex-1)*5 && i<(pageIndex)*5){
            htmlInfo +=
                '<tr><td>'+item['Jobs']+'</td>'+

                    '<td>'+item['CompanyName']+'</td>'+

                    '<td>'+item['Industry']+'</td>'+

                    '<td>'+item['Location']+'</td>'+

                    '<td>'+item['Time']+'</td>'+

                    '<td><a class="iframe" v-width="400px" v-height="400px" href="'+item['DetailUrl']+'">Detail</a></td></tr>';


        }

    });

    $('#candidateTable').html(htmlInfo);

})
```

The table generated from the code is like this:

```
<a href=" test.html?jobId=7" v-height="400px" v-width="400px" class="iframe">Detail</a>
```

The Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe : true,
    width : "55%",
    height : "75%"
});
```

})

I add the table data from JSON file, does this will affect the colorbox?
I just don't understand when I put single div in html, for example:

```
<div>
            <a class="iframe" href="test.html?jobId=10">Detail</a>
</div>
```

, and it works, but
when I use this to the table, it just open the page in another Tab Page
rather than display this page in a lightbox.

Comment: You are probably missing a closing div somewhere in your html.

Comment: did you disable javascript and made a test if colorbox works?

Comment: When colorbox works,the class of div will turn out to be "iframe cboxElement" ,but when i use javascript to create the table,the div of the colorbox is not include the cboxElement class,I just guess that when the html is load the colorbox must do something,but just don't know how to make it know that the table content include a link of colorbox,or do i need to do something after i create the table to  make the colorbox to know i got a colorbox link in the table?

Comment: Hi thenewseattle,I have fix this issue by make the colorbox to execute a little later by using the setTimeout,I guess the issue is because the colorbox execution before the table created,so now it works ,Any way,thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi frank, good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function for open the colorbox :
Ex:
A generate table from json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8kmz.jpg)

I have same problem but few changes makes it's easy Just create a function for open the colorbox :

```
function call_cbox(id) {
    $.colorbox({ href: "test.html?jobId=" + id, iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%", escKey: false, overlayClose: false });
    return false;
}
```

Call function as

:) Enjoy

i hope it's work for you 
Viresh Rajput
Noida